# Get data from complex JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, tvos, tvml

I have a complex JSON data.
How can I parse this data?
I've tried, but it does not work.

I need a Dictionary with object (id, time...). But how to get through "1,.."? 
And how can I take time begin and end?

```
"data": {

"1":[
    {"id":6524612,
     ...
     "time":{
     "begin":"18:50",
     "end":"19:20"
     },
     ...
     },

"2":[
     {
     "id":6524613,
     ...
     "time":{
     "begin":"18:50",
     "end":"19:20"
     },
     ...
     },
```

Where is my mistake?

```
  let broadcastTask = broadcastSession.dataTaskWithRequest(broadcastRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            do {
               let broadcastDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                    if let results = broadcastDict!["data"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                        for obj in results {
                            let broadcast = Broadcast(broadcastDict: obj)
                            self.broadcastList.append(broadcast)
                        }


                        //Main UI thread
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }

                } catch {

            }

        }

    }

   broadcastTask.resume()

 init(broadcastDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

        if let category = broadcastDict["id"] as? Int {
            self.id = id
        }
...
}
```

Comment: I actually don't have an answer for you but recently I've watched a great talk  by John Sundell on how to parse JSON. Hope it helps https://vimeo.com/165920052

Comment: It's quite impossible to identify the proper JSON structure because it's fragmented too much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly: 
The first problem seems to be that you are trying to cast the "data" dictionary to an array of dictionaries. This will always fail because your data object is a dictionary and not an array.

Once you correct that problem you will run into trouble with your loop. Try this:

```
for (key, value) in results {
    let broadcast = Broadcast(broadcastDict: value)
    self.broadcastList.append(broadcast)
}
```

Now you are sending the dictionary that your `Broadcast` object is expecting.

Comment: Yes, thank you! But there is a key "1", "2", how can I get the value of every numeric key? Now it takes the value like 

`{"id":6524612,
     ...
     "time":{
     "begin":"18:50",
     "end":"19:20"
     },
     ...
     },`

but I need to have access to this id, time, etc..

Comment: You can get the value from the key in (key, value) in the for loop